# Select Specific Coordinates From List

Tags: c#, logic

I have a list of coordinates (x, y) ordered from left to right, top to bottom:

[image]

My goal is to grab only some of them in a different order. I've numbered the only points I want to grab and in the order I want to grab them. Similar to Snake. The direction reverses each time I move down one:

[image]

I've attempted writing out the logic for how to select each point, but I can't seem to work out how to get it in a for loop. Or a nested for loop, I think I'll need.

`length = 10` (the size of the square of coordinates I'm grabbing. Which is 10x10.)

```
             Increments *  +
1)  length * 0 + 0 // +0 +0
2)  length * 1 + 0 // +1 +0
3)  length * 2 + 0 // +1 +0
4)  length * 1 + 1 // -1 +1
5)  length * 2 + 1 // +1 +0
6)  length * 3 + 0 // +1 -1
7)  length * 4 + 0 // +1 +0
8)  length * 3 + 1 // -1 +1
9)  length * 4 + 1 // +1 +0
10) length * 5 + 0 // +1 -1
```

So if I were to hard code the array for each coordinate I want, I would have:

```
1)   0
2)  10
3)  20
4)  11
5)  21
6)  30
7)  40
8)  31
9)  41
10) 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this requires a nested loop.

You can use a `flip` variable to change whether or not a specific line is "flipped".

- Each row has two indices to be taken
- `flip` alternates between 0 and 1, every two indices (i.e. every row)
- On even rows, the first index is `length - 1` less than the second index
- On odd rows, that relationship is flipped.

```cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int length = 11;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
            int flip = (i / 2) % 2;
            int index = (i / 2) * length + ((i + flip) % 2) * (length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
0
10
11
21
22
32
33
43
44
54
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you, I learned some new things from this.